# Update Bios on PackardBell PEW91

Tags: updates, bios

Hello Friends I have the question maybe some one of you, can help me, to
update my version BIOS like in topic i use:

*Packardbell PEW_91.
*Ubuntu = 16.10 (Yakkety Yak).

If some body can help me , and tell me  how to change that and pickup correct  KERNEL i be very grateful.